# how to add android SDK folder which is located on network drive

Tags: android-studio

my Android skd folder is located on a network drive 
how can i add it to android studio? 
the path is like this : \192.168.1.1\WD_My_46481\programs\Android\Android.SDK.Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing SMB shares via it's network path is often not possible directly within programs.
AFAIK this also applies to the Java Runtime Environment - hence it also applies to AndroidStudio because is is a Java based program.

To use a network share map it to a drive letter and use the drive letter instead.

Comment: I did that and now it can see the folder. but the android studio freezes adding the path to android studio

Answer (score 0):

go to file-> project structure ...-> SDK Location and provide path to your Android SDK like this

```
\\online\pathToSDK\SDK
```

in your case would be

```
\\192.168.1.1\WD_My_46481\programs\Android\...SDK
```